# Extract RGB values from Bitmap

Tags: c++, image, bitmap, rgb

I am currently trying to extract R, G, B  values from a 256 colour bitmap image (using for testing purposes a fixed width of 152 and height 150). I have checked using BITMAPINFOHEADER and BITMAPFILEHEADER that the offset is 1078 and bytes per pixel is 1.

The image data is initially placed in a 2 dimensional array before being placed into a 1 dimensional array. Three 2 dimensional arrays were allocated to hold the R, G, B values from each pixel.

When I run the program, the following Debug Assertion Failed! message appears:
Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID (pHead->nBlockUse)

Below is the code and I would value your expert feedback and how to fix this error.

```
    unsigned char** Allocate2DArray(unsigned char** buffer, int w, int h) 
    {  
        buffer = new unsigned char*[h];  
        if(buffer == NULL) return 0; // return if memory not allocated  
        // For each of these pointers, allocate memory of size ‘w’  
        for(int j=0; j<h; j++)  
        {   buffer[j] = new unsigned char[w];   
            if(buffer[j] == NULL) return 0;// return if not allocated  
        }  
        return buffer; 
    }  

    void DeAllocate2DArray(unsigned char** buffer, int h) 
    {  
        // After complete usage, delete the memory dynamically allocated  
        for(int j=h-1; j>= 0; j--) 
            delete[] buffer[j]; //delete rows  
        delete[] buffer; //delete the pointer to pointer 
    }


    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        ifstream image;
        image.open("image.bmp",std::ios_base::binary);

        if (image.is_open()) 
        {
            cout<< "function success\n";
        } 
        else 
        {
            cout<< "unable to open file";
        }


        const int width = 152;
        const int height = 150;

        unsigned char m_cHeaderData[1078];
        unsigned char** m_cImageData = new unsigned char* [height];

        for( int i = 0; i <height; i++)
        {
            m_cImageData[i] = new unsigned char [width];
        }

        ifstream* m_pInFile;    
        m_pInFile = new ifstream;
        m_pInFile->open("image.bmp", ios::in | ios::binary);
        m_pInFile->seekg(0, ios::beg);
        m_pInFile->read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(m_cHeaderData), 1078); 
        //bitmap bits start at offset 1078

        for(int i = 0; i <height; i++)
        {
           m_pInFile->read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(m_cImageData[i]), width); 
        }

        m_pInFile->close();


        // Declare a pointer of the type you want. 
        // This will point to the 1D array 
        unsigned char* array_1D; 

        // Now allocate memory for array_1D
        array_1D = new unsigned char[height*width]; 
        if(array_1D == NULL) return 0;  // return if memory not allocated 

        // Copy contents from the existing 2D array 
        int offset = 0; 

        for(int j=0; j<height; j++)  // traverse height (or rows) 
        {  
            offset = width * j;  
            for(int i=0; i<width; i++) // traverse width  
            {   
                array_1D[offset + i] = m_cImageData[j][i]; 
                        // update value at current (i, j)  
            } 
        }

        // Declare three 2D arrays to store R,G, and B planes of image. 
        unsigned char**arrayR_2D, **arrayG_2D, **arrayB_2D;   
        arrayR_2D = Allocate2DArray(arrayR_2D, width, height); 
        arrayG_2D = Allocate2DArray(arrayG_2D, width, height); 
        arrayB_2D = Allocate2DArray(arrayB_2D, width, height); 

        // return if memory not allocated 
        if(arrayR_2D == NULL || arrayG_2D == NULL || arrayB_2D == NULL) 
          return 0; 

        // Extract R,G,B planes from the existing composite 1D array 
        int offsetx = 0; 
        int counter = 0; 
        int bytesPerPixel = 1;

        for(int j=0; j<height; j++)  // traverse height (or rows) 
        {  
            offset = width * j;  
            for(int i=0; i<width*bytesPerPixel; i+=bytesPerPixel) // width  
            {   
                //arrayB_2D[j][counter++] = array_1D[offsetx + i+0];   
                //arrayG_2D[j][counter++] = array_1D[offsetx + i+1];   
                arrayR_2D[j][counter++] = array_1D[offsetx + i+2];  
            }  
            counter = 0; 
        }


        // After complete usage, delete the memory dynamically allocated 
        DeAllocate2DArray(arrayR_2D, height); 
        DeAllocate2DArray(arrayG_2D, height); 
        DeAllocate2DArray(arrayB_2D, height);

        // After complete usage, delete the memory dynamically allocated 
        delete[] array_1D; //delete the pointer to pointer 

        //deallocate memory:
        delete m_pInFile;
        delete m_pOutFile;
        for(int i = 0; i <height; i++)
        {
            delete[] m_cImageData[i];
        }
        delete[] m_cImageData;


        system("pause");

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: If `bytesPerPixel` is 1, then you don't have separate RGB channels in your image – it is an indexed color image. You may want to use a debugger to zoom in on the exact command that gives your assertion error.

Comment: Please create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).